# Who is בה"י referenced by the Ba'er Hetev on Shulchan Arukh, Yoreh De'ah?

Tags: halacha, translation, shulchan-aruch

The [Ba'er Hetev](https://www.sefaria.org/Ba%27er_Hetev_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.1.8?lang=bi&with=Halakhah%20ConnectionsList&lang2=en) on Shulchan Arukh, Yoreh De'ah refers to an authority named בה"י:

> לפרקים.  וזהו ל' יום. **בה''י** ועיין בבאר הגולה מה שהביא בשם מהרי''ל

Who is that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Beis Hillel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hillel_ben_Naphtali_Zevi), which appears in the Machon Yerushalayim edition in the back. It's also a separate sefer.

This particular comment can be seen [here](https://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=8061&st=&pgnum=7). It's hard to read, but there's a little daled that says לפרקים.

It's also on the Bar Ilan Database, so I'll paste the readable text:

> (ד) יראה שיחזור לפרקים. ונראה לפרקים מקרי תוך שלשים יום כדאיתא בטור או"ח סימן ק', וז"ל וכתב הרמב"ם [תפלה ד, יט] של פרקים כגון של ראש חדש ומועדות, וא"א ז"ל [רא"ש ברכות פרק ה סימן ז] כתב של פרקים הוא משלשים ואילך, ולפ"ז ראש חדש אין צריך, עכ"ל הטור. וכתב ב"י ז"ל [ד"ה וצריך] בסוף מסכת ראש השנה וכו' בברכת של ראש השנה ויום הכפורים ושל פרקים וכו', שאני רב יהודא כיון דמתלתין לתלתין יומין הוי מצלי כפרקים דמי וכו' ומ"מ מה שכתב רבינו וכו', צריך להסדיר מראש חדש לראש חדש וכדברי הרמב"ם ז"ל, עכ"ל. וכן כתב בשו"ע באו"ח סימן ק' סעיף א' תפלות של מועדות ושל ראשי חדשים צריך להסדיר תפלתו קודם שיתפלל כדי שתהא שגורה בפיו, עכ"ל. אם כן גם כאן גבי שוחט צריך שיחזור פעם אחת תוך שלשים יום כדי שתהא שגורה בפיו. וכן כותבין בקבלה שלהם, אבל אין משגיחין בזה, וצריך לזרז אותם מאוד באזהרה גדולה.

Comment: Incidentally, I was told that Rav Schachter says you can use a clean meat spoon for ice cream once in thirty days. I never knew the source, as the Shach just says infrequently. Maybe it's this Beis Hillel?

Comment: Thanks! I didn't know about the halacha for using fleishig spoon for milchigs (cold?) once in 30 days. Which siman/sif is that?

Comment: [YD 91:2](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De'ah.91.2?lang=bi&p2=Siftei_Kohen_on_Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Yoreh_De%27ah.91.3.1&lang2=bi)

Comment: Thanks. It's a long Shach, but it looks like your reference is at the end: "מיהו כל זה בדרך עראי אבל אם בא להשתמש בהן דרך קבע אפילו צונן אסור גזירה שמא ישתמש בהן חמין"